# Google maps in Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to saw google map in emulator.
I also have obtained googleApi key for that...
but when i run my code it doesn't saw just grid insted of google map.

Any help?
Thanks......

Answer (score 2):

you will have to add the below permissions in your manifest file:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

and the below library:

```
  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

inside the application tag.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the necessary permissions in your manifest? You should add:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

under the Application tag.

In your layout file, check if you have the correct API key:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:enabled="true"
 android:clickable="true"
 android:apiKey="example_Maps_ApiKey_String"
 />
```

Also, if you are just debugging, you should use the API key for the debug keystore.  For instructions on how to do that, [see here](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getdebugfingerprint).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I shared the same issue long time back,

I am enlisting some of the steps you **MUST** follow in order to get Maps Running.

1. You must have an **AVD** which is configured to target **Google APIs(Google Inc) Level 'x'**, where x can be platform specific API level. e.g. If you are using Android 2.2 Platoform create an AVC with target as Google APIs(Google Inc) Level 8
2. Well when your emulator is correctly configured, you must create an android project whoes **build is targeted to the specified API** in step 1 or lower.
3. When you create your activity which would display your Map, activity class **MUST** extend **com.google.android.maps.MapActivity** (this will not be visible until you have specified correct build target) and not normal android.app.Activity. You must also implement MapAcitivities abstract method **isRouteDisplayed().** You should also mention MapActivity extending class in your AndroidManifest.xml if you are created a new class(child of ),:`<activity android:name="IExtendedMapAcitivity"/>`
4. Another edit which you have to perform in your manifest is, you must mention Google API library being used, againg as you child of`<application>`

   ```
   <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
   ```
5. You should also mention required permissions in your manifest:
   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
6. Last and the most important step is obtaining your apiKey from google, make sure that you are using default debug keystore when obtaining that, which is present in your **C:\Users\.android\debug.keystore** [on windows]
   using application specific keystore wont work.

Your code should look like

```
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView    
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
android:id="@+id/mapview"    
android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
android:clickable="true"    
android:apiKey="[key]"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

for more info on this try http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html.

I hope this helps to you and all other newbies. Omiting any of the steps will result in not so correct behaviour of MapAcitivity.